# Proof using Contrapositive arguments

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

**Prove that if $(3x + 1)/333$ is a rational number, then x is also rational.**

I'm using only Contrapositive method to prove the statement above.
So I learnt that for contrapositive, we use $p \to q \iff ~q \to ~p$ to assume the negation of what we are trying to prove.

Now I'm completely stuck at the part where, I assume $(3x + 1)/333$ is irrational, then $x$ is also irrational. I can't seem to write the statements & would like to get some useful hints for it.

I'm new to the topic, watched a few videos that were helpful but not helpful enough for this question.

Comment: Why don't you just conclude directly? Of course, if $\frac{3x+1}{333}$ is a fraction, so is $x$.

Comment: Have you proven that if $q$ is irrational then $qa$ is also irrational for any nonzero rational $a$?  Have you proven that if $q$ is irrational then $q+a$ is also irrational for any rational $a$?  With $x$ irrational, it follows that $3x$ is irrational from which it follows that $(3x)+1$ is irrational and finally that $(3x+1)\cdot \frac{1}{333}$ is irrational.

Comment: Here is how you do it: apply the contrapositive to get the statement about irrationals. Next, how do you prove things about irrationals? Since the definition of "irrational" is "not rational", really the only way to do it is to apply the contrapositive so that you can prove a result about rationals. So apply the contrapositive a second time to get back to the easily proven result abour rationals. JMoravitz's method just handles that second application of the contrapositive in detail rather than on the whole expression.

Comment: That said, if you want practice in proving by contrapositive, prove results about irrationals where it makes perfect sense to do so, instead of proving something about rationals, where it makes no sense whatsoever. The two results that JMoravitz lists are excellent choices for this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the rational numbers are closed under the basic arithmetic operations, i.e., for any given $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, $a+b,a-b,a\times b,\frac{a}{b}$ are also in $\mathbb{Q}$ (for the last one, of course, $b$ must be different from zero). The rest will follow once you see that $x$ can be recovered from $\frac{3x+1}{333}$ via the operations mentioned above, as such, $x$ is necessarily in $\mathbb{Q}$.